# Falha ao conectar o SVN através do Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, svn

Já há algum tempo não estou conseguindo conectar o Netbeans ao SVN aqui no meu local de trabalho (utilizo a anos o Netbeans com SVN e nunca tive problemas).

Ao colocar a URL do servidor SVN, meu usuário e senha quando o Netbeans tenta conectar retorna o seguinte erro:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: 
   E175002: Connection has been shutdown:
   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: 
   handshake alert: unrecognized_name

E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/pd'
```

Alguns detalhes a respeito:

- Estou usando o SvnKit que [segundo o próprio Netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversionClients) não requer nenhum pré requisito pois já vem tudo embutido na IDE;
- O protocolo de conexão ao SVN que estou usando é HTTPS;
- Estou na versão 8.1 do Netbeans e já testei também na 8.0;
- No eclipse a conexão com o SVN com as mesmas informações funciona;
- No navegador acesso a URL e também funciona com as minhas credenciais;
- Estou em um linux.

Desde então venho procurando a solução em diversos locais porém sem sucesso.

Quem tem um ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: A sua empresa utiliza algum proxy? Já viu se o netbeans esta configurado com ele? É só a sua maquina que esta com esse problema? Verifica esses pontos..

Comment: Opa @Alberto, vamos lá: 
1-Não há proxys; 
2-tentei em outra máquina e o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você tentou acessar pelo navegador e funcionou?

Comment: Sim, pelo navegador funciona.

Comment: Consegui descobri que tratava-se de um problema de certificado do SVN aqui na minha empresa. O certificado aqui vai ser atualizado e o problema será resolvido. Porém como uma solução temporário é possível adicionar o parâmetro de inicialização `Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` que funciona. Para ajudar outras pessoas que possam ter o mesmo problema colocarei a resposta mais detalhada abaixo. Obrigado a todos pelas respostas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No meu caso em específico o problema era o certificado do servidor SVN que estava inválido/desatualizado.

Para os que por acaso se depararem com o mesmo problema que eu o correto é corrigir o certificado do servidor, mas se não estiver ao seu alcance isso ou se quiser fazer funcionar até que o certificado seja corrigido faça os seguintes passos:

- Vá até a pasta de instalação do Netbeans;
- Entre na pasta etc;
- Abra o arquivo netbeans.conf;
- Neste arquivo procure por **netbeans_default_options** que conterá diversos parâmetros de inicialização da VM;
- No final dos parâmetros antes do fechamento das aspas acrescente um espaço e adicione o parâmetro -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false, porém no netbeans estes parâmetros se iniciam com -J então ficará da seguinte forma: **-J-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false**;
- Salve o arquivo e reinicie o Netbeans.

E pronto, este mesmo parâmetro pode ser adicionado ao eclipse (sem o -J) no eclipse.ini caso esteja com o mesmo problema de certificado do SVN.